# Magento fixed shipping address on pickup

Tags: magento

I'm in need of help to locate the place, where I can set up an fixed shipping address for pick-ups.. I want our company's adress to be printed on the order confirmation, instead of the customers own adress.

But I cannot seem to locate the right spot to do so, maby a custom deliverymethod is needed?

Comment: Or just a custom observer. That adds/edits the delivery address on before the order is saved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript on the server side and Observers sales_order_place_before that will check for the payment method and adjust the address based on this